# Manage two SPA in a single ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API; One in the root and the other in "admin" route

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I have this ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API application which is used by 2 SPA Angular applications; one in "app" route and the other in "admin" route.

The routing piece of code is like below:

```
app.Map("/app", client => // =======> changed to "/" but no used
            {
                client.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "app";
                spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "app")),
                    
                };
                });
            }).Map("/admin", admin =>
            {
                admin.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.SourcePath = "admin";
                    spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
                    {
                        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "admin")),
                      
                    };
                });
            });
```

I need to go to the first application (app) in the root. I tried to change the route "/app" to "/" but it did not work.

Comment: Move admin `app.UseSpa` for app section after `app.Map("/admin")`. So it should look like `app.Map("/admin", ...); app.UseSpa(/* config for app */)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To serve the main app at root, remove its SPA middleware from inside the `.Map()` branch and move it after the admin app's middleware.

```cs
// ...
app.Map("/admin", adminApp => 
    adminApp.UseSpa(spa => {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "admin";
        // ...
    })
);

app.UseSpa(spa => {
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "app";
    // ...
});
// ...
```

So when a request to `/admin*` comes, it will follow the branch created by `.Map("/admin")` and be served by the admin SPA middleware.
For all other requests, the main branch will execute, and the main app will be served.

Comment: what about my angular project? should I use basehref="/app/" to build it?